# LaTeX - Change the overall indentation of algorithms in a book

Tags: indentation, algorithms, book-design

I am writing a document that is formatted as a book (two pages with an indentation on the left side for even page numbers and on the right side for odd page numbers).

`\documentclass[10pt,twoside,pdftex]{book}`

In my document, I want to show some algorithms.

`\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}`

My problem is that the algorithms are not indented like text and figures are.
They seem to ignore the default indentation in books and fill the entire width of the page.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

What can I do to have algorithms follow the same alignment as common text and figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in my document (I am using a template that I did not create myself) I found the following lines that are used to align figures with the indented text:

```
%Make figures as indented as the text is
\let\@oldfigure=\figure
\let\end@oldfigure=\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][!ht]
               {\begin{@oldfigure}[#1]\addtolength{\leftskip}{2.5cm}}
               {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-2.5cm}\end{@oldfigure}}
```

I was able to solve my problem by copying and adapting these lines for the algorithm environment:

```
%Make algorithms as indented as the text is
\let\@oldalgorithm=\algorithm
\let\end@oldalgorithm=\endalgorithm
\renewenvironment{algorithm}[1][!ht]
{\begin{@oldalgorithm}[#1]\addtolength{\leftskip}{2.5cm}}
    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{-2.5cm}\end{@oldalgorithm}}
```

I hope this will help someone.